# "mkdir: /Users/me/.bash_sessions: Operation not permitted"

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

When I open Terminal, I get the following error

```
mkdir: /Users/me/.bash_sessions: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea why that may be the case?  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the error message is produced by the file- `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` in the last line of this snippet:

```
# Set up the session directory/file.
SHELL_SESSION_DIR="$HOME/.bash_sessions"
SHELL_SESSION_FILE="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID.session"
mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"
```

`Operation not permitted` would suggest some kind of a file lock. Edit your post with the following command and its output:

```
 ls -lOed $HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that there's something in your profile which is incorrect. Check the contents of your shell's profile, such as ~/.bash_profile. Remove any lines you don't expect or which make reference to mkdir or .bash_sessions.