# mkdir: /Users/me/.bash_sessions: Permission denied

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

When I open terminal now I get always this error message. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
mkdir: /Users/me/.bash_sessions: Permission denied
touch: /Users/me/.bash_sessions/9F11525D-3E4C-45B5-8FA7-D69A4D2CC5B3.historynew: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284733/mkdir-users-me-bash-sessions-operation-not-permitted?s=2|2.6296

Answer (score 3):

`~/.bash_sessions` is a folder used to store the history of past bash sessions. Apparently the permissions are wrong (however this happened), there are several ways to tackle this:

- `rm -r ~/.bash_sessions` Deletes the whole folder, should get recreated with the next Terminal tab/window you open
- `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.bash_sessions; chmod 700 ~/.bash_sessions` Tries to fix permissions (`sudo` only works if you have an account with admin privileges)

Comment: The recursive option for `chown` is `-R`. Should be: `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.bash_sessions; chmod 700 ~/.bash_sessions`.

Comment: Where it says $User should I put my $pepito ? like this?

Comment: it tellms me rm -r ~/.bash_sessions - No such file or directory

Comment: @VishuVanklein `$USER` should actually be already set correctly. If you get a `No such file or directory` error the file/folder is not actually there. If this is still the same issue as the one you asked the question about 14 months back (:-)) please amend the question with the output of `ls -ld ~ ~/.bash_sessions`.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error and I was able to get past it without restarting my machine as suggested by another user. I did the following:

1. `sudo mkdir YOUR_PATH/.bash_sessions`
2. I quit and restarted my Terminal

Everything seems to be back to normal now!